# Cookie & Escaping: Store comma separated List in a Cookie

Tags: cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to store 3 values in one cookie - comma separated.
I tried this:

```
cookies[:location] = "#{params[:lat]},#{params[:lon]},#{params[:city]}"
```

the commas get escaped. Resulting in something like "%2C..."
I tried different ways with `html_safe`, `raw` and so on, but i with no success.
What am i doing wrong here? How can i create a single cookie with three or more values separated by comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma is forbidden in cookie values [rfc6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265):

```
cookie-header = "Cookie:" OWS cookie-string OWS
cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-pair )
cookie-pair  = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-value = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )

cookie-octet = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                   ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                   ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                   ; and backslash
```

**UPDATE** But this standard was not followed by browser. In my practice to pass comma you may escape `cookie-octet` by `DQUOTE` (this cookie set quoted server side by Java EE Cookie object):

```
Cookie: auth="USER,password,2014-01-01"; lang=EN
```